# Routes.Ignore not working

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-routing

I am using url routing structure for my web site.When i use url routing (especially multi segment) my css and js file not load.i used Route.Ignor but not work.

```
void RouteMap(RouteCollection route)
{
    route.RouteExistingFiles = false;
    route.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); //Not work
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.css/{*pathInfo}"); //Not work
    routes.Ignore("Styles/{*pathInfo}"); //Not work
    routes.Ignore("Styles/"); //Not work

    route.MapPageRoute("", "Guide", "~/Guide.aspx");
    route.MapPageRoute("", "Guide/{key}", "~/Guide.aspx");
    route.MapPageRoute("", "Search/{key}", "~/Search.aspx");
}

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteMap(RouteTable.Routes);
}

<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use IIS Integrated Application Pool (for css files to be processed by .NET runtime) for your application if you used classic mode.

Comment: Thanks @Gheorghe Bulicanu! should i add applicationPool property on web.config?Now then this property there isnt on Web.Config file.

Comment: @Bombula, basically you need to change applicationhost.config this file located for IIS Express located under user documents folder IISExpress\config and for full IIS under system directoy.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

`<link href="/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

`<script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

you should start your CSS or JS file path with " / " --> src="**/**Scripts/jquery.min.js"

Answer (score 0):

```
colRoutes.RouteExistingFiles = False

colRoutes.Ignore("{*allaxd}", New With {.allaxd = ".*\.axd(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*allaspx}", New With {.allaspx = ".*\.aspx(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*allascx}", New With {.allascx = ".*\.ascx(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*allashx}", New With {.allashx = ".*\.ashx(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*allhtm}", New With {.allhtm = ".*\.htm(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*allhtml}", New With {.allhtml = ".*\.html(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*allcss}", New With {.allcss = ".*\.css(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*alljs}", New With {.alljs = ".*\.js(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*allpng}", New With {.allpng = ".*\.png(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*allgif}", New With {.allgif = ".*\.gif(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", New With {.alljpg = ".*\.jpg(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*alltif}", New With {.alltif = ".*\.tif(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*allico}", New With {.allico = ".*\.ico(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*allttf}", New With {.allttf = ".*\.ttf(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*alleot}", New With {.alleot = ".*\.eot(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*allsvg}", New With {.allsvg = ".*\.svg(/.*)?"})
colRoutes.Ignore("{*allwoff}", New With {.allwoff = ".*\.woff(/.*)?"})
```